# Upgrading Xamarin.Forms in an Android app

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I'm struggling to upgrade Xamarin.Forms in an Android app. Currently, the version is 2.3.3.... and I'm attempting to upgrade it to 4.4.0... Using nuget package manager, I upgrade it to 4.4.0... I restart Visual Studio. I also upgrade the targeted framework from Android 7 to 9.

However, I receive the following error when attempting to build the solution:

```
This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.3.3.180\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20\Xamarin.Forms.targets.
```

I'm not sure if it should but the .csproj file has the following references to the Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3...

[image]

[image]

Why is this and how can I resolve this?

Update:
I've tried removing the two lines of references manually from the .csproj file. Deleted the bin/obj and packages folders. Clean and build. I then get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, manually edit the `.csproj` file(s) and delete all of the elements that reference the old version number.

The more you could refer to [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/nuget-packages-missing)

Comment: I've tried removing the two lines of references. Deleted the bin/obj and packages folders. Clean and build. I then get another error. I've included it in the OP.

Comment: What's "Instore.Apps.Menu" ?Did you quote it anywhere?

Comment: It's the assembly name for one of the projects. A portable C# library.

Comment: Did you add it in the Reference Manager ?

Comment: The reference already existed in the solution and was working before I updated the Xamarin.Forms nuget. I've removed and re-added the reference in Reference Manager and the same error appears.